# Reading data after receiving RST and socket close

Tags: c++, sockets, quickfix

I am facing a problem in an open source application (quickfix 1.13.3) while trying to read data sent to a socket on a defined port.

The problem occurs when the server sends the data and closes the socket just after it.
Then my code is not able to read last sent data, and a 10054 error is thrown.
Note that I am able to receive normally if the server do not close the socket.

This is the code i am using to receive data from server, awaiting your help;

```
int size = recv( m_socket, m_buffer, sizeof(m_buffer), 0 );
```

Note that if i uses TCPClient to receive the data it works just fine, but this will lead to create another quickfix application which means months of hard work get lost and more months to create an application similar to quickfix.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error at once when the connection closes if there is data to be received.

Comment: Also, if you get the error `10054` (`WSAECONNRESET`) then it's a sign that the other didn't close the socket in a nice way. Check the logs on the server side to see what happened.

Comment: I am sure there is data that i can read, as i said i am able to read it using tcpclient, and yes the server did not close the socket in a nice way, the server sends RST and Closes the socket

Answer (score 0):

If the server caused an RST to be sent, the semantic intent is to lose any data in flight. The server generally has no business doing that. The problem is at that end. Nothing you can do about it at the client end except possibly use a larger socket receive buffer to alter the windowing, and read faster.